# Fréchet–Urysohn subspaces in $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is called a [Fréchet–Urysohn space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space) if for each subset $A\subseteq X$ and for each point in its closure, $x\in\overline{A}$, there is a sequence (not just a net, but a sequence) $\{a_n\}\subseteq A$ that converges to $x$:
$$
a_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}x.
$$

Let $\varPhi$ be a set of *continuous* maps $\varphi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with the following property:

> each sequence $\{\varphi_n\}\subseteq\varPhi$ has a subsequence $\{\varphi_{n_k}\}$ that converges to some map $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ pointwisely:
>   $$
> \forall t\in [0,1]\quad \varphi_{n_k}(t)\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}f(t)
> $$
>   ($f$ is not necessarily continuous).

We consider $\varPhi$ as a set in the space $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ of all maps $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with the *topology of pointwise convergence* (in other words, we treat $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ as the direct product of $\mathfrak{c}=\operatorname{card}([0,1])$ copies of the interval $[0,1]$).

> **Question:** is the closure $\overline{\varPhi}$ of the set $\varPhi$ in the space $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ a Fréchet-Urysohn space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An affirmative answer to this problem is given by a Theorem on page 216 of [this book](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Sequences_and_series_in_Banach_spaces.html?id=UVmqAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) of Diestel. This theorem says that the space $B_1[0,1]$ of functions of the first Baire class is angelic in the topology of pointwise convergence. This means that each relatively countably compact subset of $B_1[0,1]$ is relatively compact and the closure of a relatively compact set is precisely the set of limits of its sequences.

By the assumption, the set $\Phi$ is relatively countably compact in $B_1[0,1]$, so its closure $\bar\Phi$ is compact and Frechet-Urysohn.

Comment: Taras, does this mean, in particular, that the closure of $\varPhi$ in $B_1[0,1]$ is already compact (so that it coincides with the closure of $\varPhi$ in $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$)?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I think so. The relative compactness means that the closure of the set in $B_1[0,1]$ is compact (if I understood correctly what was written in Diestel's book).

Comment: Interesting... OK, I'll check it. Thank you, Taras!

Comment: Taras, excuse me, if we replace $[0,1]$ by a metric compact space $X$, then Diestel's argument can't be applied directly. Is it possible that nevertheless the same is true in this general situation?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I think, we should use the fact that each compact metrizable space embeds to the Hilbert cube and use the angelicity coordinatewise.

Comment: Taras, I don't understand why the coodinate-wise angelicity implies the "general angelicity".

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Because $B_1(X,[0,1]^\omega)$ is homeomorphic to $B_1(X\times\omega, [0,1])$.